# Spinner State not Honored in Landscape

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-orientation

I have a few Spinners that I populate based on values stored in my database.  They work perfectly when I hold my phone vertically, but when I hold it sideways as I start the activity (as if to view in landscape) they all end up with index 0 selected.  In my manifest I set the activity to always display in portrait, no matter the orientation of the phone, using `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.

**Post-Answer Edit:** <snip>

I use my own BaseAdapter subclass for the Spinner, and my own custom class for its items.  I tried overriding `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` in my custom items, but that did not help.  I also set a breakpoint in the Spinner's `onRestoreInstanceState()` method to see if that was somehow involved, but it was not called.

**Post-Answer Edit:** After finding the solution, I think it is best to remove all the detail I provided previously.  It in no way helps anyone who may visit this page in the future.  See the answer to my own question below.

Comment: Try putting the setSelection() methods in onResume().

Comment: Good thought.  I just tried it.  No change.

Comment: Can you put the activity part of your manifest in your post? Also, does this happen specifically when starting the app from the adb, or also from the launcher? I've seen weird behavior along these lines when launching from the adb, especially with the screen off.

Comment: Tried unplugging the phone from my comp, force-stopping the app, and restarted it from the launcher.  No change.  I tried to add only the most essential code to my question ... there could easily be much more added, let me know if you think more code for any part of the process would be helpful.

Comment: I'm curious to see the spinner subclass. Is there an overriden method that doesn't call super? In my experience these widgets will hold state without any extra help even through actual orientation changes.

Comment: That code is very simple.  Added in its entirety.

Comment: Not sure this will help, but is there any reason for not passing context from the containing view rather than getting it in the Spinner? (In other words, try that.) And can I see SAdapter while we're at it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23537/discussion-between-eric-simonton-and-anthropomo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussion with anthropomo caused me to remember I was doing some asynchronous work in my custom Adapter class, and that seems to be the culprit.  It was a race condition.  I don't know why it consistently worked correctly when holding the phone in portrait, and consistently failed in landscape, but lesson learned.  Always remember the places you do asynchronous things, and check there first.